# Will we be ever satisfied in Jannah

Tags: jannah

What my question is  what if I be in the lowest rank Of Jannah will we have a feeling that we are in the lowest rank will we do hasad that that guy is in the upper rank than me. If we are in the lowest rank we will be there for all eternal  life.  I know Allah will grant our every wish but what if I wanted to have a house next to Prophet (S.A.W) will that be possible. Will there be a concept of rich and poor in jannah. Will the Uper rank jannaties will show pity to the lower ones.

Answer (score 2):

Allah (ﷻ) out of His Mercy grants people Paradise and gives them the level of Paradise best suited for them based on their deeds. Though everyone [including the Muslim of lowest status] would wish to have the highest level in Jannah and be next door to the Prophet (ﷺ), this is not going to be based on our wishes alone.. so do lots of good deeds and make lots of Du'a.

There will be various levels of Paradise and those in the lower levels will see the people in the higher levels. But they will not harbor any negative feelings (e.g., hasad [jealousy]) towards those people in the higher levels because Allah (ﷻ) said He will have removed such feelings in Jannah:

> ونزعنا ما في صدورهم من غلّ تجري من تحتهم الأنهار ("We will have removed whatever is within their breasts of resentment, [while] flowing beneath them are rivers") - [Qur'an 7:43](https://quran.com/7/43).

IF anything, they will just wish that they had [done more Dhikr/Worship](https://www.seekersguidance.org/answers/hadith/will-regret-heedlessness-afterlife-no-matter/) in the Dunya so that they too could've been higher. But it won't be a source of distress for them. Rest assured that each person in Paradise will be eternally happy. And [it seems](https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/47719/), from the texts, that people will be allowed to visit those whom they love in Paradise... including the Prophet (ﷺ). Muslims will see him there inshaAllah.

Answer (score 0):

A brave and excellent question. Firstly the definition of ‘satisfied’ here is relative to the individual. So technically if one’s wants are satisfied then the answer is yes. Although it is written all feeling of resentment is wiped off, I always wondered what happens when people can have conflicting wants, how is that resolved?  eg jilted lover in the padt wants someone’s spouce yet all wishes come true. I am only assuming for that to work out amicably life can be multi dimensional so that conflicts never arise. I am still gropong in the dark on your question maybe if I camebfrom Jamnah I could answer that more precisely. Not many people ask a question ad deep as yours.